# Wordpress: Display only parent category on post loop

Tags: wordpress

How to display only parent category (without child categories) on a post loop?

I have:

```
<span class="entry-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) {  
    $parent = get_category($cat->category_parent);
    if (!get_category($cat->category_parent)) {
        // do something with the category, like use it to create a new query_posts or something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get category and check `parent` field for each entry like;

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    if($categories){
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if ($category->parent < 1) {
                // Your action here
            }
        }
    }
?>
```